# Re-render React component after props change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In the React docs, it says

> By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render.

I understand for state changes, but I am not sure about when props change. As far as I am aware, props are always passed from the parent component to the child component. And when the parent component re-renders (due to a state change, for example), all child components also re-render (ignoring shouldComponentUpdate). So it seems to me that if the parent component re-renders, all child components will re-render regardless of whether I am passing new props to them or not. If I do pass new props to the child component, the fact the child re-renders is simply because the parent is re-rendering, not because I am passing new props.

<strike>Is there a scenario where a parent component passes new props to a child component, causing the child component to re-render, but it is not caused simply by the parent component re-rendering?</strike>

Is it possible to see an example where a component will re-render because it receives new props, rather than because the parent is re-rendering (or its own state changed)?

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am new to React.

EDIT: I see that Redux can cause components to re-render by passing new props, I'm curious to know what Redux is doing behind the scenes to achieve this.

Comment: This is a great question.

Answer (score 5):

**To answer the question you ask at the end:**

- If the child is a `PureComponent` or wrapped in `React.memo` it will *only* re-render if the props change. If the parent re-renders then the component will compare the props it receives and if they're identical to the previously passed props it will not re-render.
- If the child is *not* a `PureComponent` or wrapped in `React.memo` then it will re-render any time its parent re-renders.

Comment: This makes sense, but I am curious to know what would cause the component to re-render in the first place, other than its state changing or the parent re-rendering. I've updated the original question to be clearer.

Comment: A change to any React [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that your component is connected to, if any. Or calling `this.forceUpdate()` from the component. **If you're using Redux:** you can imagine what `connect` and `mapStateToProps` do behind the scenes as creating a component that grabs some `state` from Redux and passes it as `props` to its child. The child in that context is the component you're passing to React-Redux's `connect` function.

Comment: I could be wrong, but looking at Redux, it seems like Redux creates a wrapper component, and forces a render of this wrapper component if the updated Redux state would cause the child component's props to change, thus causing the child component to also re-render, now with new props. This isn't the same thing as a component re-rendering because its props have changed, if you see where I am coming from. Sorry for the confusion, I'm just trying to get a clear example of where props changing cause a component to re-render.
Also, I would think context changing is different to props changing.

Comment: The Redux `state` is *mapped* to `props`. So the Redux state that you return from `mapStateToProps` *becomes* `props` for the component. I'm not really clear on what the distinction you're trying to outline is. Context changing is different from props changing, but not meaningfully for the purpose of this discussion, unless you implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

I‘m not new to react and was asking the same thing. There was an article which made it clear for me: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/react-rendering-misconception

The re-render is needed for diff-checking if DOM updates are necessary. If you‘ve implemented shouldComponentUpdate or wrapped with memo (both returning false), then rerender is skipped.

If a child component is connected using redux or context, then it might rerender even without parent being rerendered.

Comment: The article is good, maybe my confusion is with the actual statement `By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render.`, and the props changing part of the statement implies the component is wrapped with memo?

Comment: Look at it this way: Props of a component may be the state of the parent, that‘s why it reacts similar to it. If the component implements shouldComponentUpdate or is wrapped in memo, then it will not rerender, regardless if parent changes (it rerenders only on your given condition in that method). And yes, if props/state weren’t changed but parent rerenders, then the whole tree rerenders (for diff checking, might not be a real DOM change). This is usually very fast, but once render gets expensive, shouldComponentUpdate helps you prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use provider, or HOC, or Redux with mapStateToProps for example, the props are changed from other component injecting props.

Comment: Doesn't a HOC or component using mapStateToProps still re-render (calls it's render method)?

Comment: Yes it does, and you can avoid the component to re-render with shouldComponentUpdate and so render when certains props change. Be carrefull with objects and arrays, you have to deeply compare values because references change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect middleware of redux is similar to subscription, each child component can directly connect to the store through subscription, and whenever the store changes, the store tries to resync all its connected components. New incoming data to any component comes as props resulting in re-render.
2. Any component getting changed from outside of its state can be through props only, so it is similar to a parent component passing new data / redux store pushing new data to the component.